# Query: Check previous row value

Tags: mysql

I have query like this

```
   SELECT * FROM `message` WHERE sender = 10
    ORDER BY `message`.`date` AND `message`.`topic` ASC
```

This query displays every messages.
I want to select only the first row of specific topic with the earliest date.

Is there any way to solve this by sql way?

Comment: Query should displays multiple results, but only one with specific topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to display the earliest date, and no other information in this row, it can be done very concise:

```
   SELECT topic, MIN(date)
   FROM message
   WHERE sender = ?
   GROUP BY topic;
```

If you want to display the whole row, it's a little more verbose. This example assumes that (sender,topic,date) is unique, if it isn't you need to do some extra work getting rid of duplicates.

```
WITH minDate AS
(
     SELECT sender, topic, MIN(date) AS date
     FROM message
     GROUP BY sender, topic;
)
SELECT m.*
FROM message m
JOIN minDate d ON m.topic = d.topic AND m.date = d.date AND d.sender = m.sender
WHERE sender = ?;
```